# function with ellipsis resulting in segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, ellipsis

I have the following code which is resulting in segfault error

```
    #define MAPGW_CM_TRACE(...) mapgw_cm_trace(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Function defnition goes like this..

```
    int mapgw_cm_trace(int trapLog, char *pcMsgId, ...)
   { //do something

    }
```

And I'm calling the function like this.. :

```
    MAPGW_CM_TRACE(1,"<some String>", 
                23,233, 4783274, 2138123, 23123, 21312,23112);
```

I know I might have less understanding of ellipsis. Please help me through.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: did you try debugging it? what line does it fail on?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, compilable testcase so that we can reproduce your problem on our systems.

Comment: Debugging.. yes.. exactly at this function call, it fails and throws me the segfault error..

Answer (score 1):

I could not guess exactelly the  crash cause.

But use the following macro definition instead

```
#define MAPGW_CM_TRACE(TRAP,MSGID,args...) mapgw_cm_trace(TRAP,MSGID,##args);
```

and see if it fix the crash

Answer (score 0):

What is pcMsgId, is it a format string, in which case there needs to be a matching % for each number (%d,%u,%ld or %lu), if pcMsgId isn't a format string then how does the mapgw_cm_trace function know when the arguments have ended, for an array of pointers it's usually a trailing NULL, for other types there is usually a count argument. It is also usually the case that if pcMsgId isn't a format string then the following arguments are all be of the same type as pcMsgId. Basically how is the number of arguments following pcMsgId determined.